# Error finding element with Selenium into a web form result

Tags: python, selenium

Can someone help me in this code?

Im trying to make this scraper happens, but i'm having a little trouble finishing this part:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Cpf").send_keys(sheet.cell(row=Count, column=2).value, Keys.RETURN)

results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[class*='table table-striped table-bordered dataTable'] > tbody > tr[class*=odd]")))
resultado_cnpc = results[0].text.strip() if "EmptyDataRow" in results[0].get_attribute("class") else results[0].find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text.strip()
resultado_nome = results[0].text.strip() if "EmptyDataRow" in results[0].get_attribute("class") else results[0].find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text.strip()
resultado_registro = results[0].text.strip() if "EmptyDataRow" in results[0].get_attribute("class") else results[0].find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text.strip()
resultado_uf = results[0].text.strip() if "EmptyDataRow" in results[0].get_attribute("class") else results[0].find_element_by_xpath("./td[4]").text.strip()
resultado_inclusao = results[0].text.strip() if "EmptyDataRow" in results[0].get_attribute("class") else results[0].find_element_by_xpath("./td[5]").text.strip()
```

Into this web page: http://www1.cfc.org.br/sisweb/Registro/ConsultaCNPC
with this data on second box: **336.174.128-90**

I'm getting this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./td[2]"}
```

I`m still new into python

Comment: Do you need only first row?

Comment: the 5 columns of the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all columns for the first row you can use `//table[@id='table-cnpc']//tr[1]//td[not(@class='dataTables_empty')]` xpath. This xpath handels empty results also.

```
row = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//table[@id='table-cnpc']/tbody/tr[1]")))

results = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[not(@class='dataTables_empty')]")
# or css selector
# results = row.find_elements_by_css_selector("td:not(.dataTables_empty)")
if results:
    resultado_cnpc = results[0].text.strip()
    resultado_nome = results[1].text.strip()
    resultado_registro = results[2].text.strip()
    resultado_uf = results[3].text.strip()
    resultado_inclusao = results[4].text.strip()
else:
    print("Não existe registro")
```

Comment: i keep gettin `TimeoutException: Message: ` when i try to capture blank results, can u help me to change this?

Comment: Yes, correct because I used xpath to get TD directly. Check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `./td[2]` is throwing the `NoSuchElementException` in the case where is only one `td` element under `<tr class='odd'>`. This happens in cases where there are no results in the table.

This can be resolved by checking the count of the child elements before calling `driver.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]")`. I would refactor this code to be a bit more clear on the scenario where there are search results vs. no search results.

Also, I noticed some search results show `<tr class='odd'>` and others `<tr class='even'>`. I am not sure if you intended to exclude the `even` class rows, so I will include a sample for both.

The following sample searches using the 'CPF' field, then waits for result rows to appear. The code loops through the result rows and prints out cell text. If there are no results present in the table, the loop will break.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www1.cfc.org.br/sisweb/Registro/ConsultaCNPC")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# search in CPF
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Cpf"))).send_keys("336.174.128-90" + Keys.ENTER)

# use this XPath to wait on all rows in the table -- rows are either class='odd' or class='even'
results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='odd'] | //tr[@class='even']")))

# optional: use below line to exclude 'even' rows:
#results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='odd']")))

# loop through result rows
for result in results:

    # get child td elements under this row
    child_elements = result.find_elements_by_xpath("td")

    # if there is only one td child element, then no results are present in the table
    if len(child_elements) == 1:
        print("No results returned")
    else:

        # if row has child elements, loop through elements and print text
        for child in child_elements:
            print(child.text)
```

Output from the test I ran:

```
420
FRANCISCO ANTONIO PARADA VAZ FILHO
SP-253063 / O
CRC-SP
17/06/2016
Detalhes
```

Comment: I mentioned above that in the CPF fields I used 336.174.128-90

Comment: @TitioBuga I thought you meant that was the value you were trying to retrieve from the page. The code works with that too, my answer has been updated.

Comment: I can't add your code to my code, I need to capture cell by cell of the lines with results, to be able to save it in an xlsx file.
How do I capture each result "td" and the blank results too, if they exist?

Comment: `for child in child_elements:` is capturing the `td` elements in this case. `print(child.text)` is showing that `child` IS the `td` element. If there are blank results, you can change `print("No results returned")` with adding a blank line to your xlsx (or whatever you want to do to handle the blank results). In this code sample, `result` is a row and `child` is a cell.

Comment: I need to make a `sheet.cell(row=Count, column=7).value = child.text` to save one by one, the results of the child elements, but its saving only the last one, how can i save one by one of the 6 results of the row?

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(child_elements)): sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value = child.text`